# cURL getting a response

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

Im Finding the cURL Documentation to read/Understand. what im trying to do here is post a postcode and return whether or not it is valid.
This is my function so far (what i managed to pull together from tutorials)

```
int checkPostCode(char postCode[5])
{
    printf("checkPostCode\n");

    char uidPath[200] = "http://zim.cs.uow.edu.au/~dfs/cgi-bin/postcodes.cgi?pcode=";
    //Concatinate poth strings
    strcat (uidPath,postCode);
    //Output URl
    printf("%s \n ", uidPath);

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    // Create our curl handle  
        curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)  
        {  
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, uidPath);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the script returns either a "Yes" or a "No".
I just don't know what to enter into that if statement to get my result.

thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to read a response from the server. For that you'll need to enable the option `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` and specify a callback that will receive the data from the network and store it in a array of `char`.

Comment: further help on how the call would look its it just a parameter for 
curl_easy_setopt?

Comment: Yes, but when you set it you also need to pass the name of the function (that you wrote) to handle the incoming data.